# sound output to multiple simultaneous devices in xenial

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio

I'd like to be able to play music on some speakers connected physically to my computer plus a bluetooth speaker that's in the other room, at the same time.

How do I set this up in stock Ubuntu 16.04?

Solutions that don't involve editing global pulseaudio config files are preferred.  I'd appreciate if solutions that *do* involve editing config files have specific instructions against the stock Ubuntu pulseaudio configs, e.g. "in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, make sure to add this after the `.fail` line near the top but after the `### Load audio drivers statically` section" or something.

Thanks!